# React - como faço para um input de um componente buscar uma lista que está em outro componente?

Tags: javascript, react

Criei um input para realizar uma busca de alunos numa lista, esse input está no componente Header, ele todo está assim:

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <header className='header'>
            <img src={MARCA_NEGATIVO} style={{ width: '200px' }} alt='logo'></img>
            <p>Sistema de Apuração</p>
            <p><Link to="/">Tempo Real</Link></p>
            <p><Link to="/resultado">Resultado</Link></p>
            <div className='search-bar'>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Buscar candidato' className='search'
                    onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}></input>
                <BsSearch className='search-icon' />
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}
```

e a lista está no componente PaginaPrincipal:

```
function AlunosCandidatos() {
    const [alunosList, setAlunosList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get("/api/alunos/candidatos")
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setAlunosList(response.data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Ocorreu um erro: " + err);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='container-alunos-cand'>
                {alunosList?.map(alunos => (
                    <ul>
                        <li className='li-profile'>
                        <img src={Placeholder} style={{ width: '48px' }} alt='candidate'></img>
                        </li>
                        <li className='cand-details'><b>{alunos.nome_urna}</b>
                        <li>

                        {alunos.resultado} 
                        </li>
                        {alunos.gênero >= "MASCULINO" ? (<BsGenderMale />) : alunos.gênero >= "FEMININO" ? (<BsGenderFemale />) : (<BsGenderTrans />)}
                        <BsGeoAlt /> {alunos.estado} <FaRegCheckSquare /> {alunos.raça}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Ao criar um onChange no input lá no Header, ele não consegue filtrar a lista de jeito nenhum, já tentei de tudo. Os dois estão sendo importados no App.js, então na minha cabeça deveria funcionar.

Há algum jeito de solucionar isso? Estou deixando passar algum recurso específico do React? Sou iniciante nele.

Comment: Cara nessa situação, vai ter que usar um redux (porque o estado fica global, então você acesso em todo seu projeto ) ou botar os states no App, e passar como parâmetro, porque fica como se fosse um estado global .

Answer (score -1):

Emiliy, para que você possa compartilhar um estado entre componentes, você tem algumas opções

1. Utilizar bibliotecas como Redux para criar um estado global.

   - Essa opção é um pouco extrema para quem está começando agora, mas normalmente é a solução utilizada no seu caso.
2. Passar o estado de um componente pai para um componente filho como uma propriedade.

   - Não é possível no seu caso, pois seus componentes são "irmãos", pelo o que eu entendi.
3. Armazenar sua lista de alunos como um estado do componente App e passar o estado como propriedade para sua listagem.

   - Para a pesquisa funcionar, você deverá criar a lógica dela dentro do App e passar a função de busca como uma propriedade para o componente Header.

Eu recomendo dar uma chance para a opção 3.